# How to create a hello world application using isomorphic-webpack?

Tags: isomorphic-webpack

I want to create a simple application that outputs "Hello, World!" using [isomorphic-webpack](/questions/tagged/isomorphic-webpack).

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is to use the `createIsomorphicWebpack` high-level abstraction.

First, you need to have have a basic [webpack](/questions/tagged/webpack) configuration.

webpack configuration does not need to define any special configuration for [isomorphic-webpack](/questions/tagged/isomorphic-webpack), e.g. this will work:

```js
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';

const webpackConfiguration = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    'app': [
      path.resolve(__dirname, './app')
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: []
  }
};
```

Next, run `createIsomorphicWebpack`:

```js
import {
    createIsomorphicWebpack
} from 'isomorphic-webpack';

createIsomorphicWebpack(webpackConfiguration);
```

What this does is:

- Creates a new webpack compiler.
- Runs compiler in watch mode.
- Overrides `require` to use compiled assets.

Therefore, now all you need is to require the entry script:

```js
import {
  createServer
} from 'http';

http
  .createServer((request, response) => {
    response.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });

    response.end(request('./app'));
  })
  listen(8000);
```

The entry script must be environment aware, i.e. it must return for [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) process and it must use whatever client specific logic otherwise, e.g.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import style from './style.css';

const app = <div className={style.greetings}>Hello, World!</div>;

if (typeof process === 'undefined' || !process.release || process.release.name !== 'node') {
  ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('app'));
}

export default app;
```

Since this entry script is using [css](/questions/tagged/css) and [react](/questions/tagged/react), you will need to add the missing loaders to your webpack configuration:

- [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) and [babel-react-preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/)
- [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader)
- [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack/style-loader)